# Migrating old script to new sendgrid php library errors

Tags: php, sendgrid

I recently installed the new version of sendgrid for my website. I'm getting this errors when running the script:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for SendGrid\Email::__construct(), called in /var/www/prodweb/web/sengrid.php on line 9 and defined in /var/www/prodweb/web/sendgrid-php/lib/helpers/mail/Mail.php on line 851
>
> Warning: Missing argument 2 for SendGrid\Email::__construct(), called in /var/www/prodweb/web/sengrid.php on line 9 and defined in /var/www/prodweb/web/sendgrid-php/lib/helpers/mail/Mail.php on line 851
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: name in /var/www/prodweb/web/sendgrid-php/lib/helpers/mail/Mail.php on line 853
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: email in /var/www/prodweb/web/sendgrid-php/lib/helpers/mail/Mail.php on line 854
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method SendGrid\Email::addSmtpapiTos() in /var/www/prodweb/web/sengrid.php on line 50

This is the script i was using before migrating to the last version:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once ('inc/db.php');
require("sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");

$sendgrid = new SendGrid('myapikey');

$email    = new SendGrid\Email();

$resultado = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT email, hash FROM newsletter WHERE enviado = '0' AND newsletter = '1'");
$totalRows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
if ($totalRows == 0){ // Si no encuentra registros, muestra la notificacion correspondiente
    echo "<p>No existen resultados que coincidan con tu busqueda</p>";
}

$all_users = array(); // intialzie array

while ($usuario = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $usermail = $usuario['email']; 
    $hash = $usuario['hash'];
    mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE newsletter SET enviado = '1' WHERE email='$usermail' "); 

    $all_users[] = $usermail; // push all emails first
}

// then send

try {
    $email->addSmtpapiTos($all_users)
    ->setFrom("no_responder@test.com.ar")
    ->setFromName("test")
    ->setReplyTo("no_responder@test.com.ar")
    ->setSubject("Convocatorias Semanales")
    ->setHtml('test');

    $result = $sendgrid->send($email);
    echo "enviado";
} catch(\SendGrid\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getCode() . "\n";
    foreach($e->getErrors() as $er) {
        echo $er;
    }
}
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Modify:

```
$email    = new SendGrid\Email();
```

to be:

```
$email    = new SendGrid\Mail();
```